# jQuery preventDefault to do validation before POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following block of code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form").submit(function(ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "proxy.php",
                        data: postData,
                        success: function(data) {
                                 window.location = "thankyou.php";
                        },
                        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                 console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                });
      });

  $("#form").validate({

        //a bunch of validation here
  });
});
```

The issue is that this will continue to post using ajax even though some validation fails.. why is this? Am I using ev.preventDefault() the wrong way? What I want is that for the form to be validated before I send a POST if some validation fails then just cancel, I believe that is through ev.preventDefault()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before doing your ajax request, test if the form is valid:

```
if (!$(this).valid()) return;
```

You may want to try the submitHandler option too: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Answer (score 1):

In the `validate` settings you can specify the `submitHandler` which takes a function. You can have all the validation login inside submitHandler and return true/false conditionally. Returning `false` in submitHandler will not submit the form. Try this

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // if validation is successfull return true else false.
    }
});
```